# Raspberry Pi 3B+ has erratic network connections (both Ethernet and Wifi)

Tags: networking, wifi, pi-3b+, ethernet

Running a Raspberry Pi 3B+ for several months.

The week or so, both the Ethernet and the Wifi started cutting out frequently for short periods.

At first, I thought it was just dropping packets, but a continuous ping shows frequent long packet times or drops. For example, it'll take under 1ms for 10 packets, then 120ms for one, then back to under 1ms for 10, then four unreachable.
It's "better" on Ethernet than Wifi in that the times are faster, drops are fewer and shorter, but I'm talking about drops every minute or so even on Ethernet.

Using a PoE HAT; if the power was unstable, I'd expect it to reboot or the other seven Pi 4s connected to the PoE+ switch would have issues. (Eight total RPis off one PoE+ switch that supports 120W.)

The 8 Pi sit in a case with a separate AC-powered fan as well as the onboard fans. I monitor temp via Nagios, nothing noticeable (i.e., above 60C).

The Pi is right under the Wifi router, figure less than 10"/25cm, in a wood cabinet with one shelf and the top of the cabinet above it. I doubt that's enough to cause problems.

The 1GB PoE+ smart managed switch is connected to a 24-port 1GB dumb repeater with a 1'/30cm ethernet cable, which is connected to the router via a similar cable.
Router is Unifi Dream Router (UDR).

I am running continuous ping tests from one of the seven RPi4 to all my network, only the Pi 3B+ ever has issues, and it frequently does.

When connected to the Pi 3B+ (via SSH or VNC), there are frequent pauses that also indicate network issues.

I've tried swapping cables, put it on the Cana power supply (ignoring the PoE+, thus eliminating the PoE HAT as a problem), nothing seems to help.

I don't think the microSD is the issue - shouldn't affect response to pings, and it's a Sandisk Extreme Pro 32GB that hasn't done much since installation other than answer the Nagios requests and occasionally I SSH/VNC into it.

The config uses log2ram, so even logging shouldn't wear much on it from logs.

I do back it up monthly via an automated dd script that compresses to a second microSD (in the USB port) and then moves it up to a NAS, so the entire card IS read once a month.

Any further thoughts for diagnosis?

Or should I assume the Pi is just "dying"?

Thank you.